# Invalid start and end spline points of a Highcharts graph

Tags: highcharts, spline

Is there a way to make the start and end spline points consistent with the rest of the graph. 
As they appear to be uneven compare to the others.

Comment: What do you mean "uneven"? Example code (JFiddle)?

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle. Demos on Highcharts site works fine.